# How we can define more than 2 DNS server (IP) in MAAS?

Tags: maas

in  "Upstream DNS used to resolve domains not managed by this MAAS" there is just one ip definition for DNS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see you can not define more than one DNS in MAAS web interface

you must leave the  Upstream DNS blank in MAAS web interface

and define forwarders ins /etc/bind/named.conf.options as this:

forwarders {

ip 1;

ip 2;

};

I hope this save a lot of time for you.